# error occured while running sudo apt-get install -f

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

I get this error

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so I tried `sudo apt-get clean and autoclean`.

When I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a`:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
libgtk-3-0 remmina bamfdaemon unity-2d-panel mahjongg libbamf0 simple-scan 
ubuntuone-client-gnome gnome-control-center libbamf3-0 libmutter0 evince indicator-sound
nautilus-sendto-empathy gnome-icon-theme-full update-notifier libnautilus-extension1a
libqgpgme1 cairo-dock-plug-ins gwibber libgtk-3-bin nautilus gnomine gir1.2-mutter-3.0 
vino libevince3-3 indicator-applet-complete librhythmbox-core5 zenity libunity-2d-private0
remmina-plugin-rdp cairo-dock-plug-ins-dbus-interface-python gnome-applets gir1.2-gtk-3.0 
xdiagnose gnome-shell update-manager rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder python-ubuntu-sso-client 
libcaribou0 cairo-dock-core software-properties-gtk gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 libgwibber-gtk2 
libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libgldi3 awn-applet-cpufreq libclutter-1.0-0 shotwell libpanel-
applet-4-0 unity-greeter

Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

What to do in this situation?

Comment: Can you please provide more output? The bit that actually explained the error isn't included. If you don't have it at hand, you should be able to find it in `/var/log/apt/`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The kernel dumped the process because of memory overload. Multiple errors can be caused by libraries that are not present and dependencies that are not installed. You can fix this by going to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ and downloading the software there.

Comment: Downvoted because your link is broken.

Comment: i have restarted my laptop.......but still it is here

Comment: too much in manual download......it doesn't work

Comment: @JeffWelling I edited the post and fixed the link. (You can do that too, if you see a broken link and know how to fix it--your edits will go through the approval queue.)

Comment: There is nothing in the provided output that suggests any sort of out of memory condition.

Comment: i don't think that this question has any future use (it doesn't have much data to solve). so should i delete it.